# Getting last group_id from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get last added group_id from MySQL to get new `$group_id++` for other group.

I tried

```
$group_id = ("select max(group_id) from posts");
  $group_id++;
```

But when I check it with echo

```
echo $group_id;
```

the result is : "select max(group_id) from posts"

Comment: You have written a query. But you have to run it. Please check how to run a query and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning a query string to a variable..you're not even running the query...?

You need to run the query and assign it to a result ($group_id_)

There's other ways to do this but this is similar to what you're doing.

```
$result= mysqli_query($conn, "select max(group_id) as max from posts");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
$group_id = $row['max'];
$group_id++;
```

Comment: @FilipDržik try that

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not executing an SQL query, you are doing an assignment.

The correct syntax is something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Search how you can execute SQL queries, and if you have trouble, post again.

**Edit:** Have a look on the link below

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Don't use mysql_query. It is deprecated. Use Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Mysql is deprecated and you should be using mysqli

Comment: @clearshot66 yeah, my mistake... corrected it as soon as I saw that.... small typo

Answer (score -2):

This is the easiest way to implement it the latest one will have the highest ID so you order them by their id starting from the highest id to the lowest and you just take the first one.

Read about the http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php it explains everything about querying data from your database using php.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
if($result = $mysqli->query("select group_id from posts ORDER BY group_id DESC LIMIT 1")){
// it has returned a result
$group_id = $result->fetch_object();
$group_id++;
}
```